# Confusion about $1/|\vec{p}|$ in helicity operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, helicity

The helicity operator is defined as
$$
h = \frac{1}{|\vec{p}|} \vec{\sigma} \cdot \hat{\vec{p}}
$$

One of the first exercises into QED is to check whether this commutes with the Dirac Hamiltonian. Should the question arise, everyone will say (or the books will hint), that $1/|\vec{p}|$ is "just a number" (hence no hat on that bit). Years ago when I took the course of quantum electrodynamics I didn't pay this much attention, but now I revisited this concept and I'm confused.

We know, that $\hat{\vec{p}} = - i \hbar \vec{\nabla}$, so to find an operator that corresponds to $|\hat{\vec{p}}|$ would mean to find an operator that, when applied twice, gives $- \hbar^2 \Delta$. People usually shrug this off as unnecessary and that $|\vec{p}|$ is to be understood as just a real number.

$1/|\vec{p}|$ can be "just a number" only if the state we're applying this operator to is an eigenstate of the momentum operator (i.e. a plane wave). It can be then shown (in p-representation, where any operator composed of $\vec{p}$ is interpreted as multiplication), that $1/|\hat{\vec{p}}|$ gives $1/|\vec{p}|$.

Moreover, if it's so easy to just shrug off this whole issue about $1/|\vec{p}|$ as it being just a number, why did Dirac obsess so much about finding a square root of the Klein-Gordon equation? He could just say "well, anything here is just a number, so we plug in the corresponding numbers and then take the square root."

Does anyone have any satisfactory answer to clear my confusion? Please, if you think you do, I indulge you to calculate the following commutator
$$
\left[ 1/|\hat{\vec{p}}|, x_i \right]
$$

Comment: What book says it is “just a number”?

Comment: Peskin-Schroeder introduce helicity in the same way and use p as a unit vector in p-direction. Since we have no commutation relations for components of unit vector aligned with p and position components, I assume, that they again, treat the normalization as a number. If not, I'd very much like to see what's the commutation relation [p_i/sqrt(p^2}, x_j] equal to.

Comment: I might be wrong, so correct me if I am, but isn't the definition of helicity just $h = \vec{\sigma} \cdot \hat{\vec{p}}$, the component of the spin in the direction of the momentum?

Comment: @Philip divided by |p|, so that (as per standard explanation/motivation) the possible result is +-1, rather than +-|p|

Comment: Ah, right, the problem is the hat means both "operator" as well as "unit vector", and I got a little confused. I meant it in the unit vector sense, which makes it the same as what you have.

Comment: Yep. And as for my original question, now that the confusion is cleared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

As for $1/|\vec{p}|$ being just a number this is allowed, since the Hamiltonian for free particles does not contain position, just momentum ($H = \vec{\alpha} \cdot \hat{\vec{p}} + \beta m$), so operator-ness of $1/|\vec{p}|$ is not important.

However, it is still possible (and potentially useful) to discuss this as an operator. I tried to derive a few commutation relations as an exercise and it is possible

$$
\left[ x_i, | \hat{\vec{p}} | \right] = \frac{i \hbar \hat{p}_i}{\left| \hat{\vec{p}} \right|}
$$

$$
\left[ x_i, 1/| \hat{\vec{p}} | \right] = - \frac{i \hbar \hat{p}_i}{\left| \hat{\vec{p}} \right|^3}
$$

Example how the first one can be shown: we use the fact, that no matter how complicated an operator is, it always yields the appropriate eigenvalue on plane waves $e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}}$.

$$
\left[ x_i, | \hat{\vec{p}} | \right] f (\vec{x}) = \left( x_i |\hat{\vec{p}}| - |\hat{\vec{p}}| x_i \right) \int \mathrm{d}^3 k \, f (\vec{k}) \: e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}} = \\
= x_i \int \mathrm{d}^3 k \, f(\vec{k}) \left( | \hat{\vec{p}} | e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}} \right) - \int \mathrm{d}^3 k \, \left( - i \frac{\partial f}{\partial k^i} \right) \left( | \hat{\vec{p}} | e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}} \right) = \\
= x_i \int \mathrm{d}^3 k \, (\hbar k) \, f (\vec{k}) \: e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}} - i \int \mathrm{d}^3 k \, (\hbar k) \, \frac{\partial f}{\partial k^i} \: e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}} = \\
= x_i \int \mathrm{d}^3 k \, (\hbar k) \, f (\vec{k}) \: e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}} + i \int \mathrm{d}^3 k \, \left( \frac{\hbar k_i}{k} + i \hbar k x \right) f (\vec{k}) \: e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}} = \\
= i \hbar \int \mathrm{d}^3 k \, \left( \frac{k_i}{k} \right) f (\vec{k}) \: e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}} = \frac{i \hbar \hat{p}_i}{\left| \hat{\vec{p}} \right|} f (x)
$$

In the first line I just wrote out the commutator and expanded the function in plane waves, on the second line I used that $\left\langle k \right| \hat{x} \left| \psi \right\rangle = i \partial_k \, \psi (k)$, on the fourth line I integrated by parts (throwing out the boundary term, since $f$ is as quickly going to zero as needed) and finally I interpreted the integral on the last line as the result. Any $p$-related operator can be treated like that:

$$
\left[ x_i, f(| \hat{\vec{p}} |) \right] = i \hbar \, f^\prime (| \hat{\vec{p}} |) \frac{\hat{p}_i}{\left| \hat{\vec{p}} \right|}
$$